# How to embed XML using server side only?

Tags: html, xml

Using this example: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=simple&xsltfile=simple

I have three files:

- My html page (fancy CSS, header and footer etc) with a div called "content" which is where the breakfast menu would be displayed.
- My XML file (breakfast menu)
- My XSLT file

Currently, I only know how to display individual .xml files on my browser by adding:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="myxsl.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

How would I go about displaying data from the .xml file into an already built HTML page? My conditions are:

1. No Javascript allowed.
2. No frames.
3. Visitor is not allowed to see .xml file

Which I suspect leads to SERVER side processing (I'm using a WAMP server). Any help here? I'm not an experienced XML or web person, please dumb it down for me ;)

EDIT: I only need to do selects, for loops and sorting. So basic XSLT stuff, I can understand.

Update: If I may, my working solution:

```
# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor(); 
$XSL = new DOMDocument(); 
$XSL->load('hello.xsl'); 
$xslt->importStylesheet($XSL); 

# LOAD XML FILE 
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load('hello.xml');

#PRINT 
print $xslt->transformToXML($XML);
```

Comment: But client-side processing conflicts with requirement 1 (no Javascript allowed).

Comment: Sorry, it's been a late night: it should be server side :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform the XSLT transformation of the XML file on the server and spit HTML to the client. Here's an [article](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/xsl.html) which illustrates the concept using PHP.

Comment: My PHP is pretty basic, could you run me through what I would do with the example above? My html page is basically the content div between header and footer.

Comment: Or maybe provide a php snippet that would allow me to do this.

Comment: @stockoverflow, that's really a matter of XSLT syntax. In PHP all you need is to load the XSLT document (which references an XML document) and call the `transformToXML` method which will return you the resulting HTML (look towards the end of the article - `Performing the XSL Transformation` paragraph, it contains all the necessary PHP code).

Comment: Cheers Darin, slowly digesting this but I'm getting there now (though I was a bit thrown off by the pagination). Can you please explain the optional parameters section? Is it required for my case?